# VS Code doesn't show text proberly

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, fedora

So I installed VS Code on my linux-fedora machine and my text/code is not centered in the center of the line. It looks like its some kind of superscript and I can't find a way to change it.
At first it was just fine, but after some time it changed. I did nothing in settings and   I even reinstalled fedora, but  I still had the same problem. In normal text editors I don't have this  problem, but I installed Atom too and had the same problem.

Code is not centered in line:
[image: Code is not centered in line]

Comment: you mean vertically? that's the font you are using.

Comment: the text is as big as the line numbers, what is the problem, the screen image looks good, which character is "wrong"

Comment: yeah I changed the font and now it works!